# Rails: undefined method 'MODELNAME' ? Am I saving the wrong thing on create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently I'm making an app for users to create picture albums. The catch is that there can be multiple owners for each album, so in the form to create an album there is a check box portion where you highlight your friends names and "invite them" to be an owner. However, I am having a hard time getting it to work since it's giving me an error in my `AlbumsController#create`. The error is :

`undefined method 'user' for #<Album:0x007fcd9021dd00>`

`app/controllers/albums_controller.rb:43:in 'create'`

Here's my form

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @album]), :html => { :id => "uploadform" } do |f| %>
<div class="formholder">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <br>
    <label>Hosts</label>
    <% @user.friends.each do |friend| %>
    <%= friend.name %>
    <%= check_box_tag 'album[user_ids][]', friend.id, @album.users.include?(friend) %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

The checkboxes return an array of `friend.id` values that I want to invite to be owners for the album. The tricky part here is that I have a imaginary `pending_album` column in my join album_user model. Here's what is sending me errors that I can't figure out how to fix:

albums controller

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album], :status => 'accepted')
  @friends = @user.friends.find(params[:album][:user_ids])
  for friend in @friends
    params[:album1] = {:user_id => friend.id, :album_id => @album.id, :status => 'pending'}
    AlbumUser.create(params[:album1])
  end
      #the next line is where the error occurs. why???
  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end
```

album model

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :user_ids
  validates_presence_of :name

  validates :user, :uniqueness => true

  has_many :album_users
  has_many :users, :through => :album_users
  has_many :photos

end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :profilepic
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

validates_format_of :name, :with => /[A-Za-z]+/, :on => :create
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 5, :on => :create
# validates :album, :uniqueness => true

has_many :album_users
has_many :albums, :through => :album_users, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
has_many :pending_albums, :through => :album_users, :source => :album, :conditions => "status = 'pending'"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums

has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
has_many :requested_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'requested'", :order => :created_at
has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'pending'", :order => :created_at

has_attached_file :profilepic

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

def name_with_initial
  "#{name}"
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
```

end

album_user join table model

```
class AlbumUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_ids, :album_id, :status, :user_id
  belongs_to :album
  belongs_to :user
end
```

parameters (looks a little fishy... especially since album_id is nil):

{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"xkIi6+1vjEk4yQcFs9vI1uvI29+Gyuenyp71vhpX9Hw=",
 "album"=>{"name"=>"123123",
 "user_ids"=>["27",
 "28"],
 "description"=>"123123"},
 "commit"=>"Create Album",
 "user_id"=>"29",
 "album1"=>{"user_id"=>28,
 "album_id"=>nil,
 "status"=>"pending"}}

I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone help please!!

Comment: I would recommend taking your `AlbumsController#create` and putting each chunk of functionality in a function in the appropriate model, and then test each function. Doing that will probably make it easier to find the bug.

Comment: ooo you mean separate each chunk and make them methods and store those methods in the model? which model would i put it in?

Comment: That will require some judgement, but it looks like probably mostly in the `User` model. For example, it looks like you could use a function to find a user's friends...or something. Another advantage of separating your code into separate functions is that your intentions will probably be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is:

```
undefined method 'user' for #<Album:0x007fcd9021dd00>
```

All right, so something's calling `Album#user`. Line 46 in the controller is `@user.save`, so how is `user` getting called?

```
class Album < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :description, :user_ids
  validates_presence_of :name

  validates :user, :uniqueness => true    # <-- bam!

  has_many :album_users
  has_many :users, :through => :album_users
  has_many :photos
end
```

`save` triggers validations, including that line right there, which validates that `user` is unique. Since this is exploding, I'm guessing that `user` is a column that doesn't exist, either because a) it's not defined in a migration or b) you didn't run the migration.

(As an aside, I'm rather confused as to why you would have a unique `user` attribute on `Album`, an `AlbumUser` model with both `user_id` and `user_ids`, and a `User` model. Maybe it makes sense, but I think it's more likely that it all needs a cleanup.)

Comment: hey will. I actually don't remember why I added that line with the unique user... can you explain more on what you meant here? " an AlbumUser model with both user_id and user_ids, and a User model. Maybe it makes sense, but I think it's more likely that it all needs a cleanup."? I think I had those attributes because errors kept popping up about mass assignment, but I too did not understand why they popped up

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to me that a model would have both `user_ids`, indicating a `has_many :users` relationship, *and* `user_id`, indicating a `belongs_to :users` relationship. Which is it?

Comment: since this is a many-to-many relationship, I would say `has_many :users` should be correct. Where are you seeing `belongs_to :users`?

Comment: Ah, but `AlbumUser` is really a join table (breaking apart `has_and_belongs_to_many`), so it should be `belongs_to :user`. And so it is. However, `AlbumUser` also has `attr_accessible :user_ids`. There's no schema posted, so I can only imagine why.

Comment: oo ok I can paste my schema. I'm also getting a new error but this time on my show action, so I'm assuming the create action works properly now. It's saying that it can't find a album with `status = 'accepted'`, even though I indicated that in my controller#create... mind if you take a look? I'll upload it now

Comment: I've made a new one in case you're curious http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12847349/rails-status-not-properly-being-inserted-into-params

Answer (score 1):

Your album really has many several users? Then that should return method "user"? If want that one user owned album you must use `belongs_to` in your model. Then method "user" will return correct user to album