# Rails: "status" not properly being inserted into params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'm currently receiving an error on form submission. My app is basically one with users, albums, pics (for picture uploading). However, when I try to create a new album, it is giving me the error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in AlbumsController#show

Couldn't find Album with id=123 [WHERE "album_users"."user_id" = 29 AND (status = 'accepted')]

The catch is that there can be multiple owners for each album, so in the form to create an album there is a check box portion where you highlight your friends names and "invite them" to be an owner. This is why my create function looks a little weird. The issue here is getting the :status => 'accepted' to insert normally. Please help!

albums controller

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album], :status => 'accepted')
  @friends = @user.friends.find(params[:album][:user_ids])
  for friend in @friends
    params[:album1] = {:user_id => friend.id, :album_id => @album.id, :status => 'pending'}
    AlbumUser.create(params[:album1])
  end
      #the next line is where the error occurs. why???
  if @user.save
    redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end


def show
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.find(params[:id]) #error occurs on this line
end
```

user model :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :profilepic
validates_presence_of :password, :on => :create

validates_format_of :name, :with => /[A-Za-z]+/, :on => :create
validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
validates_length_of :password, :minimum => 5, :on => :create
# validates :album, :uniqueness => true

has_many :album_users
has_many :albums, :through => :album_users, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
has_many :pending_albums, :through => :album_users, :source => :album, :conditions => "status = 'pending'"
accepts_nested_attributes_for :albums

has_many :friendships, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
has_many :requested_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'requested'", :order => :created_at
has_many :pending_friends, :through => :friendships, :source => :friend, :conditions => "status = 'pending'", :order => :created_at

has_attached_file :profilepic

before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

def name_with_initial
  "#{name}"
end

private

  def create_remember_token
    self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
```

end

Comment: replace `@user.albums.build` with `@user.albums.create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
@album = @user.albums.build(params[:album], :status => 'accepted')
```

makes no sence. Only `params[:album]` will be respected. Use Hash#merge to combine `:status` and `params[:album]` (without modifying the last one):

```
@album = @user.albums.build(params[:album].merge(:status => 'accepted'))
```

**Beware!**

You've specified conditions on your `albums` association:

```
has_many :albums, :through => :album_users, :conditions => "status = 'accepted'"
```

But it won't be taken into consideration on making associated albums (like `@user.album.build`). You have to specify it **like a hash**:

```
has_many :albums, :through => :album_users, :conditions => {status: 'accepted'}
```

to be treated with respect. This way you won't be needed to pass `:status` in `build` calls. The value of `:status` will be set automatically to `'accepted'`.

Comment: hey thanks for the advice jdoe. but now i'm getting another error: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: albums.status: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "albums" INNER JOIN "album_users" ON "albums"."id" = "album_users"."album_id" WHERE "album_users"."user_id" = 29 AND ("albums"."status" = 'accepted')`. Does the `status` column have to be in the album table? Cuz I thought it should be put in the album_user model

Comment: @Edmund If you have to pass additional options for a join model (AlbumUser in our case) then you can create relationships manually: `AlbumUser.create status: 'accepted', user: @user, album: @album`. It wasn't clear from your code the model your `status` belongs to.